# Execute a function from a function object

Tags: python, function

*In all of the examples, `a` is :*

```
>>> def a():
...     print "aaaaaaa"
```

I have been passed a function object from another piece of code, and I need to execute that function.

When I say "function object", I mean an object like this:

```
>>> type(a)
<type 'function'>
```

Have a look at this:

```
>>> def function(f):
...     print "start"
...     f
...     print "end"

>>> function(a)
start
end
```

If `function()` was executing the function it was passed, the output would have an `aaaaaaa` in the middle of it (returned from `a()`, which was the function passed to it)

So how can I execute a function when passed the function object?

*(Sorry if this isn't very clear, I'm confusing myself as well...)*

Comment: Consider using valid python code in your questions.

Comment: @Martin, Sorry, I've done all of this in the IDLE shell.

Comment: Your updated code now looks like the shell, but it's still not valid python. Although it is slightly easier to read (perhaps), it's more difficult to paste into an interpreter or file to test out.

Comment: (I didn't add the `...`s) Would you like me to change it?

Comment: It's your question - do what you like. However, with code any more complex, or which requires debugging, you will be doing yourself, and anyone minded to help you, a disservice by making it more difficult.

Comment: Yeah... I guess with more complicated code I would use the shell in the first place.

Comment: The shell creates those additions.

Comment: I mean I would not use the shell... typo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call it using the [function call operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) `()`:

```
f()
```

This is how you would have called `a` after defining it.  The global name `a` points to the same function object as the local name `f`, so you need to do the same thing to call them.